# Usages and nuances of tie to/tie up/tie down

Tags: phrasal-verbs

The verbs *tie to/tie up* and *tie down* relate to limits put on somebody or something and which make somebody/something unavailable. There are several dictionary examples of these verbs occurrences:

> **(1)** I'm tied to the job while I have mortgage to pay.
>
> **(2)** She's tied up in the meeting at the moment, but I'll ask her to call you later.
>
> **(3)** All my money is tied up in property.
>
> **(4)** I don't want a relationship that ties me down.

My question is are these verbs wholly interchangeable or are there any slight differences of their meanings? Looking into the examples I would suppose that *tie down* is used when we say about people but not about money. On the other hand, I think of *to* peposition function as a pointer on a limit and, in my opinion, it doesn't exclude using *up* or *down* at once, so can I append *up* or *down* to *tied* in **(1)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence works well as it is, without up or down.
If you want to add a particle, "down" would be better.
I think "tied down" refers to a longer term restriction, like a mortgage or a relationship. "Tied up" refers to a short term limitation, like being stuck in a meeting or on another call, or literally strapped to a chair by a kidnapper.